# Pâtisserie versus pâtissière

Tags: usage, alimentation

I just visited a French pâtisserie this morning called “*Ludo's Patisserie*”, but was surprised to see their take-home price-list titled “*Ludo's Patissiere*” (accented characters not being used in either representation).

Looking it up when I got home, I see that “*pâtissière*” is a female pastry chef, but it's also used in the name of the French pastry cream, “*crème pâtissière*”. So it's left me confused why the price-list was titled as it was.

Is there a difference between “*Ludo's pâtisserie*” and “*Ludo's pâtissière*”, or am I looking at a simple spelling mistake by their printers?

Comment: Where is the shop located? In a French-speaking country, in an English-speaking country, in Canada?

Comment: In an English speaking country where very few people speak French.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ludo's Patissiere* may be

- a typo
- Ludo's female pastry chef
- Ludo's *crème pâtissière*
- A *Noix pâtissière* (a certain piece of veal)

> **Noix pâtissière** (according to [servicevie.com](http://www.servicevie.com/bien-manger/dictionnaire-culinaire/noix-patissiere/i/5672))
>
> *Définition*
>
> Pièce de boucherie: morceau de veau tiré du cuisseau (plus précisément du muscle antérieur de la cuisse).
> C'est une viande de grande qualité, moins cependant que la noix elle-même. On la détaille en rôtis ou en escalopes.

but since crème pâtissière is hardly ever sold alone, *noix pâtissière* is no pastry and Ludo has hardly female pastry chefs enough to sell them to everyone, I tend to think that it's a typo.

Comment: I wouldn't exclude the possibility of someone wanting a French touch on his business and using a dictionary to find related words without remarking that they made no sense as used. The important question is obviously: are the pastries good?

Comment: The chef is French and has been a pastry chef for 35 years so I'm thinking that probably wouldn't have been the case. The pastries? The pecan pie I had was very average (crust way too thick, fatty and no crunch, pecans only on surface of caramel instead of through out it, served too cold).

Answer (score 3):

My first take is that this is the name of a shop in an English-speaking country, because of the `'s` (which wouldn't make sense in French). The name is “Ludo's [shop], [Ludo being a] female pastry chef”, with “female pastry chef” being expressed in French to look sophisticated. This construction (name, genitive mark, noun designating a type of shopkeeper) is fairly common in shop names in English-speaking countries. For example, [Waterstones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterstones) used to be called “Waterstone's booksellers”.

In French, the prevalent corresponding construction is “chez Ludo — pâtisserie” or “pâtisserie chez Ludo”, though “chez Ludo, pâtissière” is also possible.